# JavaFX Timeline control

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I want to create a scrollable timeline controller with circles connected to a baseline filled with a number ( size of circle corresponding to containing number) and a trailing icon.

Since I am new to JavaFX i have no idea how to start. In `Swing` i would e.g. use `JPanel` and ovverride its `onPaint()` method to draw the circles, lines and icons...

In JavaFX I thought about using a horizontal `ListView` with custom `ListCell`, but i am not sure if the baseline is possible with it. So i am looking for ideas how to implementiert such a controll...

[image: Timeline controller sketch]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a [`HBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/HBox.html) wrapped inside a [`ScrollPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html).

You can add elements to HBox using `getChildren.add(node)`. The elements will be automatically shown on the scene and the ScrollPane will adjust the ScrollBar for you.